# compilation error with binding a template function to a gtkmm signal

Tags: c++, templates, binding, g++, gtkmm

I have some callback functions :

```
class someclass
{
  private:
  bool someCB1(GdkEventFocus*,GtkEntry*);
  template<class T> bool someCB2(GdkEventFocus*,T*);
};
```

somewhere in the code of `someclass` I have a `Gtk::Entry* entry`. If I connect `someCB1` :

```
entry->signal_focus_out_event().connect( sigc::bind<Gtk::Entry*>( sigc::mem_fun( this, &someclass::someCB1 ), entry ) );
```

this one works, but in my case I want to use `someCB` with different kinds of `Gtk::Widget`, so I wrote the template function `someCB2`

to connect `someCB2` I wrote :

```
entry->signal_focus_out_event().connect( sigc::bind<Gtk::Entry*>( sigc::mem_fun( this, &someclass::someCB2 ), entry ) );
```

this line failed at the compilation, errors are very numerous (I cannot scroll my console to the first one, but the last ones are similar, so I guess like the rest). Here the last one :

```
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/mem_fun.h:6356:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/user/chicken.cc:158:111: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T_arg1’
   entry->signal_focus_out_event().connect( sigc::bind<Gtk::Entry*>( sigc::mem_fun( this, &someclass::someCB2 ), entry ) );
```

can someone tells me what I mess ?

Comment: You have exactly the same problem as [him](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016749/forwarding-arguments-to-template-member-function) (although it's a different usage) you can solve this by explicitly telling the compiler which `someCB2` you want to use (I mean, with which types) [Edit: also, I have the feeling you're trying to use templates to achieve dynamic polymorphism, that won't work, use virtual methods for that]

Comment: @Caninonos actualy I don't see how I can tell wich type to choose (all my tries fails)

Comment: @Caninonos thx for your participation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `&someclass::someCB2` the compiler has no chance to deduce what type `T` should be when using it with `mem_fun()`. If the address of the class is directly used with something allowing to deduce the template argument it would work.

In your case you probably want to use something like the below instead:

```
 static_cast<bool (someclass::*)(GdkEventFocus*, GtkEntry*)>(&someclass::someCB2)
```

Alternatively you can also specify the template argument directly:

```
&someclass::someCB2<GtkEntry>
```

Comment: Ah, too slow, i shouldn't have done something else :p Well at least: [example](http://ideone.com/5HTimW) (with dummy signals/slots, no encapsulation because I'm lazy and it's not relevant here)

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl thank you. Actualy when I read `&someclass::someCB2<GtkEntry>` I was of course... call me `esel`... I don't write template very often and I forget the place of the `<GtkEntry>` I tried by adding it before `someclass` and `someCB2`...